# How to add extra menu item while tapping for long time on a contact of phonebook?

Tags: qt, events, symbian, tap, contactitem

I don’t know whether it is possible or not. But what i want to do is, when my app is running on background i want to add an extra menu item when user is using the system phonebook and pressing a contact for long time. For example Symbian^3 and later phones when we press a contact for longer time a pop up menu appears having some default menu items like:

Call
Send Message
Add to Favourite
Send as Business Card
Delete
Mark

Now I want to add another menu item like “MyItem” when my app is running in background. Is it possible to do in Symbian using Qt, or using Basic Symbian ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible in Symbian C++ (not in Qt). The framework that serves these requests is called `RSendAs`. You have to write your own Message Type Module (MTM) and register it to the Send As framework. I warn you that it can be quite difficult. Unfortunately I did not do this but I know there are [applications out there](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php?145128-E71-E66-MTM-Contacts-gt-Send-Option-not-showing) that succeeded with this.